# Hub for bluetooth mouse and keyboard

Tags: keyboards, bluetooth, mice, kvm

I have a bluetooth mouse and keyboard which I use for my personal and work laptops, sometimes they will both be on at the same time and I'll need to switch between them. This is a bit of a pain, is there anything on the market which makes this easier? I'm envisaging a sort of hub to manage the devices and switch the direction of the input from mouse and keyboard to the active device - similar to a KVM switch, does any such thing exist for bluetooth?

Comment: While I personally dislike bluetooth mouse/keyboard, I think your question is a school example, how trivial and obvious wishes are simply... unsupported by everything. I believe your problem could be solved by an embedded device having 2 stupid, or 1 smart bluetooth chip. It could act as a bluetooth bridge. I hope someone already did it and you can buy.

Answer (score 1):

You could get something like this [USB Switch](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Sharing-Keyboard-Scanner-Printer-Black/dp/B01N6GD9JO/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=usb%20kvm&qid=1591343035&sr=8-3) and attach a USB Bluetooth adaptor to it.

It allows you to connect up to 4 USB devices and then it can connect to up to 2 PCs / Laptop with a single USB cable. With the touch of a button you will be able to switch between PCs / Laptop.

Comment: That's a really neat idea - I'll give it a try and report back with findings :)